# Processing emails that were not processed by Items_ItemAdd procedure

Tags: vba, outlook

I am processing incoming emails with **`Items_ItemAdd`** but sometimes its stops working and I am trying to find out why.

Meanwhile, I would like to know how I can process the emails that are on the inbox and weren't processed with **`Items_ItemAdd`** procedure without to have to resend them to the inbox again.

Comment: I have the same problem - to work around it I created two subfolders with a rule to move the emails to be processed to one the folders.  If the code doesn't run (as it seems to always do these days) I just manually move the emails to the second folder and back again - then it executes.  No need to pick them out of the inbox then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx

```
Sub ProcessUnprocessed
' Counting backwards in case items are moved or deleted in ItemAdd code
' Count backwards always. Never use For Each (Notes to self.)
For i = ActiveExplorer.Selection.count to 1 step -1

    watchedFolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal ActiveExplorer.Selection(i) As Object)

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm wondering how large - my code use to process 100+ emails in a few seconds when moved to the folder using a rule, but then decided to stop working unless I manually moved them.